# Why my python executable does not default to /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python, macos, configuration, path, homebrew

On my macOS computer, I have installed python using Homebrew in /usr/local/bin. In a newly opened terminal, I have

```
$ echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/qazwsx/.local/bin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
/Users/qazwsx/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
```

As you can see /usr/local/bin appears before /usr/bin. But somehow python finds the default one!? Why?

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Does `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'` really work for you on MacOS? Because that doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: Are you making the necessary adjustments and exporting the PATH in your bash_profile? Did you source it after you finished?

Comment: What does `$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` reveal? How about `$ type python`.

Comment: Also try running `brew doctor` to see if anything is out of whack.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local/bin/python` probably does not exist. I noticed that recently on my macOS computers, after I upgraded Homebrew, there is no longer a `/usr/local/bin/python`. When I re-install python using `brew reinstall python`, it warned to add `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/` to `$PATH`. After reinstalling, there was indeed a `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python` but not a `/usr/local/bin/python` any more. There is instead `/usr/local/bin/python2` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Answer (score -2):

A work-around to this would be to rename the old python and create a symlink to your version.

```
mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.0
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

As to why it's not defaulting, not sure.  It could be a number of things.. perhaps there is a symlink to python in another directory higher up in the list, the `which` command may use a different path, or you're calling it from a different shell environment with a different path setting?

Comment: Starting in El Capitan (OS X v10.11), [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) forbids modifications in /usr/bin (and a bunch of other system directories), even as root. And even in earlier versions, changing things in /usr/bin was a bad idea -- for example, there are many system scripts written in Python, and if you swap in a different version (specially version 3), some of them may break. And having random system components stop working is not good.

Comment: Another example of Apple trying to control everything in the environment :( even thought he OS they're using they snatched from the open source community.